# what is the aim of create schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use Schema in my database only for grouping tables, views, stored procedure, functions and other object by subject, and I dont realy know where schema must be used, and why schema tab is below security tab in SSMS.

EDIT :

[image: Schemas]

Comment: why schema tab is below security tab in SSMS? please more explain about main point of your question

Comment: vote up or down answer and accept if it was useful for u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schemata are a way to logically group objects so that consistent permissions can be applied to all of them through the schema rather than individually. Consider:

```
create schema [foo] authorization [dbo]
grant select on schema::[foo] to [user1]
create table [foo].[table_1] (...)
create table [foo].[table_2] (...)
create table [foo].[table_3] (...)
```

By placing all of the tables in one schema, I was able to grant permission at the schema level and that notion of permission trickled down to all of the tables contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

i think this placement is because of mapping between security of users (roles and users) and schemas. not data structure of schema, like tables and columns and so on.

if you go to security tab -> Users-> double click on on of the users. you find that you can edit mapping between that user and owned or role membership of SCHEMAs.

im hopeful to be useful for u.